# .htaccess redirect to subdirectory if no 'www.' in requested URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'd like to keep users at the main directory of my domain if they enter the domainname as www.mydomain.de , but redirect them to a subdirectory if the domain is entered without the "www.". I know it makes little sense, but I desparately need it for temporary testing purposes while preparing a website.

I've tried with

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://mydomain.de/subdir/$1 [L]
```

but it doesn't do the trick. Can anyone point me to the right direction please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the forward slash in the rewriterule and change your condition. You can try it this way.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^/?$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!subdir).*)$ http://mydomain.de/subdir/$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks! Strangely, the testing tool at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ says the htaccess is fine, but when used on my server, it doesn't work and gives a 500 error (internal error)?

Comment: is it possible the error is  caused because the domain contains umlauts? My htaccess looks like that now: RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xn--krisen-lsen-yfb\.at$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xn--krisen-lsen-yfb.at/new/$1 [L]
(should redirect to the "new" subdirectory if the URL is entered without "www.")

Comment: with the above definition, the server redirects me to http://www.mydomain.de/subdir/subdir/subdir/subdir/subdir/subdir[..]....